# getting other rank value than 1 in oracle in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

There is 1 SQL query when i used like below-

```
select * from
(select a.id, a.nm, b.pd, b.date, rank() over(partition by a.id order by b.date desc) rnk 
 from tab1 a, tab2 b where a.id = b.id) 
where rnk =1
```

then getting output like below-

```
id    nm    pd    date         rnk
--    ---   ---   ----------   ---
11    abc   a15   11/04/2022    1
11    abc   a15   11/04/2022    1
14    gef   a23   11/04/2022    1
14    gef   a23   10/04/2022    12
19    lfb   a37   11/04/2022    1
19    lfb   a37   08/04/2022    21
```

But I want only one value to be select as order by latest date. Could you please help me on this to resolve it to select one value for 1 id like below-

```
id    nm    pd    date         rnk
--    ---   ---   ----------   ---
11    abc   a15   11/04/2022    1
14    gef   a23   11/04/2022    1
19    lfb   a37   11/04/2022    1
```

Comment: For a single row with the latest date, try row_number() over(....) instead of rank()...

Comment: @SOS I used row_number() as well but not getting output as I am expecting.

Comment: What was the actual result and how was it different than what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a second column in the order by of the `RANK()`, so that there are no duplicate pairs of values (e.g. `b.id`). I've also normalised the `JOIN` operation.

```
select * from
  (select 
     a.id, 
     a.nm, 
     b.pd, 
     b.date, 
     rank() over (
        partition by a.id 
        order by b.[date] desc, b.id asc
        ) as rnk 
  from tab1 a
  join tab2 b on a.id = b.id
  ) s
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thank for answer but unfortunately it is SQL syntax error showing as `missing right paranthesis`.

Comment: I've modified slightly please try again. If it still doesn't work please give table definitions and some sample data, preferably as a fiddle. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcdf57be02b7cd95bebafe415c498022

Comment: I used with `,` as well inside `rank()` function but getting same output that i got earlier not like expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this because sometimes `rank()` function doesn't work just outside main SQL. Try it, hope it will work.

```
SELECT id,
       nm,
       pd, date
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT a.id,
             a.nm,
             b.pd,
             b.date ,
             rank() over(PARTITION BY a.id
                         ORDER BY b.date DESC) rnk
      FROM tab1 a,
           tab2 b
      WHERE a.id = b.id))
WHERE rnk =1
```